# Class Diagram to Entity-Relationship Diagram (Relationships and Cardinality)

Tags: uml, class-diagram, polymorphic-associations, erd

Are the multiplicities of associations and aggregations in an UML  class diagram the same as the cardinalities of the relationships in a relational database (Entity-Relationship Diagram)?

Answer (score 0):

### In short

Yes, the concept of multiplicity in UML is the same than cardinality in ERD.  The main difference is the terminology.

### Demonstration

First of all, we need to keep in mind the original meaning of [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality), which means the number of elements in a given set.

The UML 2.5.1 specifications explain page 33 that

> The ***cardinality*** of a collection is the number of values contained in that collection. The ***multiplicity*** of a MultiplicityElement specifies valid cardinalities of the collection it represents. The ***multiplicity is a constraint on the cardinality***, which shall not be less than the lower bound and not greater than the upper bound specified for the multiplicity (unless the multiplicity is unlimited, in which case there is no constraint on the upper bound).

To make it short, the collection here refers to the instances of a class that are linked to a given instance of another class. So the UML definition says that the multiplicity defines the constraints that exist on the allowed size of such sets.

Interestingly, [Peter Chen](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/320434.320440), the inventor of the ER model does not mention at all cardinality in his first papers.  Chen speaks of "*mapping types* `1:1`, `1:n` and `n:m` and explains that:

> Information about the ***number of*** entities in each entity set  ***which is allowed*** in a relationship set, is indicated by specifying "1","m","n" in the diagram.

We have to be careful about the terminology.  Here, the *entity* refers to a specific set of values for some attributes, i.e. an instance, whereas the *entity set* refers to all the possible instances of what we colloquially call "entity".

In conclusion, the wording of ERD and UML might be slightly different, but in both cases, it is about constraints regarding the number of instances on one side may be related to instances on the other side.